# How to fix Acrobat X text blurry text when using 2D graphics acceleration?

Tags: graphics, adobe-acrobat

When I enable 2D graphics acceleration in Acrobat, the text becomes abnormally blurry.

I have an excellent graphics card with the newest drivers, so I dont think those are the problem.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by the "Antialiasing - FXAA" setting for NVIDIA graphics cards.

To fix it, one can either turn off that settings either globally, or turn it off only for Acrobat.

Comment: Also, if you're AMD Radeon: in the Catalyst Control Center there is an "MLAA" function that would have the same effect.